# How to verify if a field is an empty string with GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a GORM query and I need to make it avoid a field which may be a empty string for legacy system questions.

Currently, my query is:

```
def things = Thing.withCriteria{
    resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP
    createAlias 'factor', 'f'
    eq 'active', true
    isNotNull 'title' // this field may be an empty string
    isNotNull 'content' // this field also may be an empty string
    // <-- and here I'd like to include sth like isEmpty 'title'
    not {
        inList 'f.id', factors
    }
    projections{
        property 'id'       , 'id'
        property 'f.name'   , 'name'
        property 'title'    , 'title'
        property 'content'  , 'content'
        property 'f.id'     , 'factorId'
    }           
}
```

I didn't find any solution in the docs, but I have a feeling that this solution should be with pure SQL. Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding this statement to the criteria?

```
ne title, ""
```

Grails criteria relies on [hibernate Restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html), so everything supported by this can also be used in grails criteria.

Otherwise you could also use [sql restrictions (see Using SQL Restrictions section)](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria):

```
sqlRestriction "char_length(title) > 0"
```

Keep in mind that `title` here refers to the real column name in the database. If you want to have a more reliable code, you can include a static mapping for the field (column name) in the model :

```
static mapping = {
     title column: 'title'
}
```

In this way you should avoid errors from db specific naming behaviour (if any).